# Android Custom Dialog Design

Tags: android, dialog

I am working on a custom dialog design for my application. However, I have some problems with the design. I want to create the following:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the dialog]

I have almost everything done, only one part is missing.
The border which I highlighted here in black (which is in the real application white, background color of the dialog) should be transparent but only this black part.

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="335dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_circle"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:translationZ="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-35dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_big"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_dialog_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#2e7b8a"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close2"
            android:id="@+id/imgClose"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgClose"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your xml here

Comment: you have to just put floating button  and put image inside else u can take frame layout

Comment: The image is at the place, but instead of the transparent border (higlighted in black) there is the white background of the dialog

Comment: Try to use PopupWindow instead of dialog with custom layout.

Comment: @Chris try my code which i have posted

Comment: Your code is for a dialogfragment, not a dialog right? My current class extends Dialog and not DialogFragment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your dialog class:

```
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

This removes the title and most likely the border. If you are using DialogFragment, you can also define the style like this:

```
    int style, theme;

    style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME;
    theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog;


    setStyle(style, theme);
```

Comment: actually, maybe. change the root element to framelayout, and set the full background where there is an issue to transparent.. It has to be FrameLayout because it allows you to have multiple elements overlapping. Once inserted, move the xml code of the background as far up in the xml code as possible(so it is in the back)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it now with a Framelayout and one extra line of code:  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: I'm adding it to the answer so it is easy to see for people in the future with this problem

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
 <style name="MY.DIALOG" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>


</style>

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MY_DIALOG);

}
```